# dictionary returned different format after using dict.get() in Python udf

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below:

```
{"field":{"check_list":[{"order_list":[{"item_list":[{"type":"new","make":"usa"}]}]}]}}
```

I have functions which takes in the dictionary (the parameter "data") and search inside the dicionary to return the item_list:

```
def get_order_list(data):
    order_list = []
    for i in data.get("field", {}).get("check_list", []):
        order_list=i.get("order_list",[])
    
    return order_list


def get_item_list(data):
    #get order list first
    order_list =get_order_list(data)

    item_list=[]
    
    for j in order_list:
        item_list=j.get("item_list",[])
        
    
    return item_list
```

My desired output is like this:

```
   [{"type":"new","make":"usa"}]
```

But what I got from the "get_item_list" funcion is like below:

```
   [{type=new,make=usa}]
```

Why does the dictionary format get changed here?
What should I do to just get the exact value of the key"item_list"?

Comment: Hi, I want to help you but I need some clarity. I think your thread will be much more understood if: 1. why do you refer to the function as udf? 2. what is the desired outcome? 3. what does get_order_list do or at least how does the output look like, in relation to the output shown? 4. how do you know that you get `[{type=new,make=usa}]` it seems very unlikely that this is an exact thing you will see if you'll print the dat

Comment: 1. I am using the function in a pyspark dataframe. I think I used the word udf wrong here. 2. please see update. 3. please see  update. 4. that would be a desired outcome, which is the exact list from inside the dictionary

Comment: The edit clarifies a lot but I still can't figure out exactly what you are trying to do. Could you please a less trivial example of input you want, and what is the desired output?

Comment: In the get_item_list function, your item_list variable is getting *replaced* for each j in the for loop, you'll only get the last one. Did you mean to accumulate with item_list.append(j.get("item_list",[])) maybe ?

Comment: @theshopen the desired output is [{"type":"new","make":"usa"}]. I just want to get the dictionary value of the key "item_list"

Comment: @joao yeah that may be a problem as well. but most of time i only have 1 item in the litem_list. i ran it and i still got the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it had an error in line `for i in data.get("fields", {}).get("check_list", []):` because it is field in the dictionary so it will return blank list .If you change thid line to `for i in data.get("field", {}).get("check_list", []):` it will work. That showed me desired output.I have used the code on online compilers as well as vscode.